# How to assert that a function throws an exception?

Tags: exception, ocaml

I can catch exceptions:

```
try some_fn () with | e -> print_endline "exception caught!"
```

but what about the other way around, detecting that a function does not throw an exception (when it should)?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to write some very hacky way to achieve that: I create a wrapper around the function I want to test, which throws some specific exception at the end. I catch anything but that exception.

```ml
exception Finished

let check (fn : unit -> unit) =
  let wrapper _ = (
    fn ();
    raise Finished)
  in
  try wrapper () with e when e <> Finished -> ()
```

in utop this works:

```ml
utop # check (fun _ -> ());;
Exception: Finished.
```

```ml
utop # check (fun _ -> failwith "hey");;
- : unit = ()
```

EDIT: my coworker suggested:

```
let should_fail fn =
  if Result.try_with fn |> Result.is_ok then failwith "this test should fail"
```

Comment: typically you woud return true/false: `let c f = try f() ; raise Finished with | Finished -> false | _ -> true`

Comment: As a side note, there are local exceptions in OCaml, eg: `let check (fn : unit -> unit) = let exception Finished in let wrapper ...`

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions can be handled within pattern matching cases, allowing very clean expression for this check:

```ml
match some_fn () with 
| exception _ -> print_endline "exception caught!"
| _           -> print_endline "error: no exception raised!"
```

We can abstract this check into a function:

```ml
let throws_exception f =
  match f () with 
  | exception _ -> true
  | _           -> false
```

Which we can use in an assertion like so:

```
assert (throws_exception (fun () -> raise (Failure "msg")))
```